# Position: Fixed element is overflowing window

Tags: html, css, css-position, overflow

I created a container which is fixed at the bottom of the page. However, the container then overflows off the page and the padding rules are completely ignored. I have searched around the forum but cannot find a solution in my problems context. I have tried using position absolute, and also tried using Javascript to calculate the scrollbar width to no avail.

```css
.restaurant-page {
  height: 100%;
}

.restaurant-page .book-table-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.restaurant-page .book-table-container button {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #00ccbc;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="restaurant-page">
  <div class="book-table-container">
    <button>Book Table</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is hard to understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you mean that the button is cutoff to the right. You can prevent that by adding: `.restaurant-page .book-table-container { left: 0; right: 0; }`.

However the button wil then touch directly the left and right side of the screen. To prevent that I added a padding of 5px to the left and right and shortended the padding code from: `padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 12px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;` to: `padding: 12px 5px;`.

```css
.restaurant-page {
  height: 100%;
}

.restaurant-page .book-table-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
  padding: 12px 5px;
}

.restaurant-page .book-table-container button {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #00ccbc;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

/* for demonstration only */

body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="restaurant-page">
  <div class="book-table-container">
    <button>Book Table</button>
  </div>
</div>
```